# get value from MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$query  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `user_name` = '$from' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $fromID = $row['user_id'];
}
```

I'm trying to have $formID be the user_id for a user in my database. Each row in the Users table is like:

```
user_id | user_name | user_type
   1    |  Hristo   |   Agent
```

So I want `$from = 1` but the above code isn't working. Any ideas why?

Comment: Doesn't look to me like you have a live connection to the DB. Can you show us the code where you used `mysql_connect`?

Comment: You are right. I wasn't connecting to the DB. Now I am and its giving an error. FireBug says 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: What if my username is `1'; DROP TABLE Users; --`

Comment: From what I see from your comments, could it be that you never reach this part of your code at all?

Your echo doesn't print anything, and you get 500 errors.

Try to place something like `die('Reached line: '.__LINE__);` somewhere between your db-connect and this query, and see if that message appears. If it does, place it after the query and see if it still appears...

Comment: You're right... I'm never getting past the line `$result = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_name = '$from' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $fromID = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Also, make sure that:

- You have connected to the database
- You do get data from the post, try `var_dump` with your vars eg `var_dump($from)`

Comment: I am now connected to the DB and $from, $to, $message are all correct!

Comment: Access denied for user 'Hristo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Hristo: This means you are not connected to the database. Make sure that you are specifying the correct database info. Also see: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/connect-to-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: @Sarfraz... I believe I am connected to the database because I can successfully display usernames in another section of the code. I'm still investigating it and it is probably a stupid mistake. But I'll go back and check the database connection code. Thanks.

Comment: You were right... I apologize. I THOUGHT I was connected to the database because I remember putting in the `require_once("db.php")` but I probably deleted it with Ctr-Z. Works now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead

Comment: doesn't seem to be working... I think I'm never getting inside the loop... I put an echo $fromID after the assignment inside the while loop and it didn't print anything :/

Answer (score 0):

`while($row =`[**mysql_fetch_assoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)`($result)){ $fromID = $row['user_id'];
}`

Comment: doesn't seem to be working... I think I'm never getting inside the loop... I put an `echo $fromID` after the assignment inside the while loop and it didn't print anything :/

Answer (score 0):

though it should.
try this code

```
$from    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
$to      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `user_name` = '$from' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$fromID = $row['user_id'];
echo $fromID;
```

if it will throw no errors but still print no id, add this line

```
var_dump($row);
```

and post here it's output

not that you shouldn't use a user name but user id to address particular user.

Comment: I wasn't connecting to the database... now I am and its giving an error

Comment: @Hristo well that means either you can see no errors or you have no such record in your database. Ensure both things

Comment: Thanks. The only error information I have is from FireBug and it says `500 Internal Server Error`. I'll keep trying. Thanks

Comment: @Hristo  to see actual error message you have to refer toweb-server error_log. Can you find one?

Comment: /private/etc/apache2/error_log says "[Tue Jun 15 12:49:44 2010] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant PASSWORD - assumed 'PASSWORD' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jQueryChat/db.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/jQueryChat/chat.php"

Comment: line 5 from db.php is "define(PASSWORD, 'password');"

Comment: I'm getting a password denied for my user. That is my problem. 
"Access denied for user 'Hristo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: @Hristo nice. have you solved this connection problem already? Though you should use my code anyway, cause I have many errors repaired.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet... had a meeting with da boss. I'm back to it now. Can you explain your use of `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);`? Whats wrong with doing `$from = $_POST['from'];`?

Comment: It turned out that I wasn't connecting to the database even though I thought I was... I deleted require_once("db.php") by accident with Ctr-Z. Works now!

Comment: @Hristo nice. as for the code, I have answered recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047393/how-do-i-prevent-sql-injection-with-php-and-mysql/3047407#3047407