# How do you properly set a blank variable as NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I am parsing an XML feed into a MYSQL table using simplexml_load_file().  Some of the variables are blank, I would like them to be actual *NULL* instead of NULL, or is there even a difference?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('cb.xml') or die ('Bad XML File');
foreach($xml->item as $item) {
    $name = $item->name;

//Tried

if ($name == '') {
    $name = 'NULL';
}

//And

if ($name == '') {
    $name = NULL;
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO cb (name) VALUES ('$name')");
```

Comment: The second would work by chance on ORACLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're giving MySQL a string:

```
.... ('ANYTHING WITHIN QUOTES IS A STRING')
```

And the PHP `null` value, when "casted" to a string, becomes an empty string. So your first try gave `... ('NULL')`, and now it gives `... ('')`.

You must use the `NULL` keyword inside the query, without quotes, to insert `NULL` into a database field.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cb (name) VALUES (" . ($name == null ? "NULL" : "'$name'") . ")");
```

Oh, and as usual, take care not to get SQL-injected with your unprotected `$name` variable.

Comment: I got that to work, I am just having trouble using that syntax with more than one VALUES variable.

Answer (score 2):

The second variable initialization is correct; the first is just the string 'NULL' (which is not special from PHP's viewpoint).  However, you should be using prepared statements ([MySQLi_STMT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) or [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).  If you want to stick with the regular mysql extension, use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

An example with PDO is:

```
$stmt = $pdo_con->prepare("INSERT INTO cb (name) VALUES (?);");
$stmt->execute(array($name));
```

This will handle nulls correctly, unlike your current string interpolation.

Comment: Can you give an example of a prepared statement?  Because when I use just NULL instead of 'NULL' MYSQL still shows a blank field.

Comment: Here's a [previous answer I gave explaining prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340533/filtering-out-mysql-query-in-php/3340616#3340616).  Know them, use them, love them.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using more than one value and shorthand if else does work then do this: (we will insert the null data in column 3) * Notice that the single quotes are omitted.. this is because "NULL" cannot be entered in as a string for sql or else it will be a string NULL not an SQL NULL which is what we want.

```
//condition
if ($col3_var !== NULL)
   $col3_var = "'$col3_var'";
else
   $col3_var = "NULL"; //SQL will omit the "" here

$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename
       (col1, col2, col3...)
       VALUES
       ('$col1_var', '$col2_var', $col3_var)";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Err: " . mysql_error());
```